# SKCanvasView event args contains only Pressed action type

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

My Sample custom control inherits from the `SKCanvaView` and overrides the `OnTouch` method. It simple prints into the Debug stream action type, however, the action type is always the type of `Pressed`.

From my understanding, I should get action types like `Pressed`, `Released`, `Moved`, `Cancel`.
Why I'm getting **only** the `Pressed` action type?

Version information:

```
Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0.2012
SkiaSharp.Views.Forms v2.80.2
```

Tested with Android device running in Hyper-V as well as a physical device, both with same results.

```cs
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

namespace PurpleBlue.MobileApp.Controls
{
    public class SampleControl : SKCanvasView
    {
        public SampleControl()
        {
            EnableTouchEvents = true;
        }

        protected override void OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SampleControl: {e.ActionType}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
[0:] SampleControl: Pressed
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
[0:] SampleControl: Pressed
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
[0:] SampleControl: Pressed
[ViewRootImpl] ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

Control used in view

```xml
<controls:SampleControl 
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    HeightRequest="60"
    WidthRequest="120"
    BackgroundColor="Aqua"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil is in the detail, one has to mark as handled in the event handler. Once one does it, magic happens and the app correctly handles the remaining action types.
The correct version of the event handler is the following.

```
protected override void OnTouch(SKTouchEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"SampleControl: {e.ActionType}, mouse: {e.MouseButton}");

    e.Handled = true;
}
```